Detecting .NET8 with Inno Setup and InnoDependencyInstaller
I am looking at using InnoDependencyInstaller and it has a function that it uses under the hood:
Dependency_AddDotNet80
procedure Dependency_AddDotNet80;
begin
  // https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/8.0
  if not Dependency_IsNetCoreInstalled('-n Microsoft.NETCore.App -v 8.0.0') then begin
    Dependency_Add('dotnet80' + Dependency_ArchSuffix + '.exe',
      '/lcid ' + IntToStr(GetUILanguage) + ' /passive /norestart',
      '.NET Runtime 8.0.0' + Dependency_ArchTitle,
      Dependency_String('https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/593685c9-7e98-455a-8e34-4b8ad1be9489/6ccf85c6fc244428d61f74ca3aee0645/dotnet-runtime-8.0.0-win-x86.exe', 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/7f4d5cbc-4449-4ea5-9578-c467821f251f/b9b19f89d0642bf78f4b612c6a741637/dotnet-runtime-8.0.0-win-x64.exe'),
      '', False, False);
  end;
end;

My query is with this test:
if not Dependency_IsNetCoreInstalled('-n Microsoft.NETCore.App -v 8.0.0')

I think the latest installer of .NET8 is greater than 8.0.0. So will this test fail? I would ask on the GitHub repository page but there is no way to create an issue there.

Footnote: Here is a related question on this subject, where it refers to 8.0.3:

Check if .NET 5.0 is installed in Inno Setup


Update
I thought I would at least try installing on a laptop I have and manually running the console application.
So, in InitializeSetup I make a call to Dependency_AddDotNet80; and compile my software. And, I run the installer on the laptop.
It displays the following:

So it indicates that it will install the .NET Runtime 8.0.0 (x86). Two concerns:

It is referring 8.0.0.
It is referring to x86.

My application is built for AnyCPU but this is a 64 bit laptop. After installation I try to run the console application:

It can't find the x64 runtime. Delving more into the GitHub example / repository I see that there is a Dependency_ForceX86 variable and it is used in one place in their code:
function Dependency_IsX64: Boolean;
begin
  Result := not Dependency_ForceX86 and Is64BitInstallMode;
end;

I think I am digressing now! Going back to my original query about Dependency_IsNetCoreInstalled I find that it does this:
function Dependency_IsNetCoreInstalled(const Version: String): Boolean;
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  // source code: https://github.com/dotnet/deployment-tools/tree/main/src/clickonce/native/projects/NetCoreCheck
  if not FileExists(ExpandConstant('{tmp}{\}') + 'netcorecheck' + Dependency_ArchSuffix + '.exe') then begin
    ExtractTemporaryFile('netcorecheck' + Dependency_ArchSuffix + '.exe');
  end;
  Result := ShellExec('', ExpandConstant('{tmp}{\}') + 'netcorecheck' + Dependency_ArchSuffix + '.exe', Version, '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) and (ResultCode = 0);
end;

Don't know if the above helps with this? So I essentially have 2 related queries:

How can we ensure that we are checking for (and downloading) the latest .NET8 using this system? Ideally the feedback to the users should state it, eg. 8.0.3.

How can we install both the x86 (if required) and x64 versions of the .NET8 runtime?


It is a pity that this excellent GitHub tool doesn't add any logging into the installation log. The only thing I gleaned is that it it downloaded netcorecheck.exe into the temporary folder for using during installation.
I have now added a comment to his article but it is in moderation.

I noticed that in his article he says:

The dependencies are installed based on the system architecture. If you want to install 32-bit dependencies on a 64-bit system, you can force 32-bit mode like so:

Dependency_ForceX86 := True;  // force 32-bit install of next dependencies
Dependency_AddVC2013;
Dependency_ForceX86 := False; // disable forced 32-bit install again

But I did a test on my Windows 11 x64 with this code:
  begin
  if Is64BitInstallMode then
    MsgBox('Installing in 64-bit mode', mbInformation, MB_OK)
  else
    MsgBox('Installing in 32-bit mode', mbInformation, MB_OK);

  begin
  if IsWin64 then
    MsgBox('Is Win 64', mbInformation, MB_OK)
  else
    MsgBox('Is Win 32', mbInformation, MB_OK);
  end;  end;


It says it is Win 64. Good.
But it also says it is installing in 32 bit mode. Not good.

My installer is for both. It includes both 32 bit and 64 bit executables in the same folder. It is just the way I did it.
So this bit in his code is returning that it is x86:
function Dependency_IsX64: Boolean;
begin
  Result := not Dependency_ForceX86 and Is64BitInstallMode;
end;


CodeProject views and reputation can help that author, so you should try to leave your question there to reach the author (and likely why that repo has no issue section).

@LexLi Here you go (https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5380204/Detecting-NET8-with-inno-setup-and-innodependenciy). Currently it is in moderation.

@LexLi you mean here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20868/Inno-Setup-Dependency-Installer

I have created a pull request for the 8.0.3 bit. https://github.com/DomGries/InnoDependencyInstaller/pull/92

It was suggested in the comments that I ask this question on CodeProject. So I did:
Detecting .NET8 with Inno Setup and Inno Dependency Installer
This is because the actual GitHub project is advertised on that platform:
Inno Setup Dependency Installer
The response there was:

As this appears to use netcorecheck, it means that the version check is an exact version, so passing 8.0.0 inside looks to see if that version is installed, so if you need 8.0.3, this would have to be passed in.

I have therefore created a pull request for this issue.
As for the problem about not installing the x64 version of .NET8 … I decided to change to build two distinct installers, one for 32 bit and one for 64 bit, each going to the correct program files folder.

Update
The pull request has been accepted and merged. 
